# How to use attributes of two different tables in view of third table in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Rails and got stuck while trying out an application.

- tables: car , customer , purchase
- car table attributes: id, carname, carmodel price
- customer table attributes: id , custname , custaddress, contact
- purchase table attributes: id ,carid, custid, amount , purchasedate

I used the following associations in my models:

- car: belongs_to: customer
- customer: has_many: purchases, has_many: cars
- purchase: belongs_to: customer

When accessing the purchase controller's show method and view templates, I want to display the details for the customer and purchased cars as well, what should I do?

Your approach or guidance will surely help me and will be appreciable.
thanks in advance

Comment: you can access them by `@purchase.customer.cars`, `@purchase.customer`